# how to get top 2 dates from series

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am new to pandas and I am trying to find out what the top 2 dates are in a specific column. I have an excel sheet called "test" that I am connecting to using pandas. Here is the data for that column:

```
date_col
1/1/2018
2/1/2018
2/1/2018
2/1/2018    
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
2/1/2018
2/1/2018
2/1/2018
2/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
2/1/2018
2/1/2018
3/1/2018
3/1/2018
```

However, when I run the following code:

```
print(test['date_col'].nlargest(2))
```

I get:

```
3   2018-03-01
4   2018-03-01
Name: date_col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

what I really want is

```
3   2018-03-01
4   2018-02-01
Name: date_col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

because those are the top 2 dates, regardless of the duplicates. I tried using 'first' but I get the same result:

```
print(test['date_col'].nlargest(2,'first'))
```

could someone point out to what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) first:

```
print(test['date_col'].drop_duplicates().nlargest(2))
16   2018-03-01
1    2018-02-01
Name: date_col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Alternative solution:

```
print(test['date_col'].drop_duplicates().sort_values(ascending=False).head(2))
16   2018-03-01
1    2018-02-01
Name: date_col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: gosh, that was so simple. thank you so much. Isn't the parameter KEEP for the nlargest supposed to do that too?

Comment: @user7146708 - Hmmm, I test it and it seems it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

One way via built-in `sorted`:

```
sorted(df['date_col'].drop_duplicates())[-2:]

# [Timestamp('2018-02-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-01 00:00:00')]
```